# Mysql query design help needed

Tags: mysql

Have this mysql query

```
SELECT CE.codreg, CO.id FROM table1 CE left join table2 CO ON CE.codreg=CO.registro ORDER BY CE.codreg ASC
```

My problem is that in table2 may have more than one rows for one CE.codreg and need to select only the one that have the max CO.id of the rows for this one CE.codreg

How could I do?

Comment: Look, this question is asked about a dozen times a day. It gets a bit boring.

Comment: Look my last reply to Bushan comment. ;)

Comment: Yeah, Bhushan would do well to read up on some recent similar threads too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CE.codreg, CO.id 
FROM table1 CE left join table2 CO ON CE.codreg=CO.registro
where CO.id=(select max(I.id) from table2 I where I.registro=CO.registro)
ORDER BY CE.codreg ASC
```

**Edit1**

Try this if you want the rows from table1 even if there is no record in table2

```
SELECT CE.codreg, (select max(I.id) from table2 I where I.registro=CO.registro)
FROM table1 CE left join table2 CO ON CE.codreg=CO.registro
ORDER BY CE.codreg ASC
```

**Edit2**
Edit1 will return row for every record in table2, to avoid that here is the alternative.

```
select CE.codreg, (select max(I.id) from table2 I where I.registro=CE.registro)
FROM table1 CE
ORDER BY CE.codreg ASC
```

**Edit3**
Try this:

```
select SELECT CE.codreg, CO.*
FROM table1 CE left join (select * from table2 I where I.id=(select max(I2.id) from table2 I2 where I2.registro=I.registro)) CO ON CE.codreg=CO.registro
ORDER BY CE.codreg ASC
```

Comment: Hi, first thanks but with this only selects rows that have match with table2 but I need that selects all registers of table1 and If table 2 have match (left join) selects the max. Thanks

Comment: @Hanzo Please see `Edit1`, and let me know if this doesn't works. I have tried this in oracle10.

Comment: But this only selects max CO.id of the rows but I need that  "SELECT CE.codreg, CO.*" all of the fields of CO that id is max(id). Thanks

Comment: I think that i not explain correctly. For every record of table1 can be various records of table2. I need join to every record of table1, if exist, the record of table2 that have the max id of the records of table 2 ( where table1.codreg=table2.registro). Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: @Hanzo Please see `Edit3`.